# How to change key bindings on MBP

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

By default I have to hit fn+up arrow and fn+down arrow for page up and page down actions, but those buttons are on opposite sides of the keyboard. I want to be able to do rshift+up and rshift+down.

I already tried System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> App Shortcuts, but it only lets me map to menu items.

Comment: It wouldn't be it App Shortcuts; those shortcuts are system wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do what I wanted by installing Karabiner and adding a file here:

```
$ nano ~/Library/Application\ Support/Karabiner/private.xml
```

I added the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>

  <item>
    <name>Custom Shortcuts</name>
    <item>
      <name>Shift + Up = Page Up</name>
      <identifier>custom.pageup</identifier>
      <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CURSOR_UP, VK_SHIFT | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::PAGEUP</autogen>
    </item>
    <item>
      <name>Shift + Down = Page Down</name>
      <identifier>custom.pagedown</identifier>
      <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN, VK_SHIFT | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::PAGEDOWN</autogen>
    </item>
    <item>
      <name>Shift + Left = Home</name>
      <identifier>custom.home</identifier>
      <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, VK_SHIFT | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::HOME</autogen>
    </item>
    <item>
      <name>Shift + Right = End</name>
      <identifier>custom.end</identifier>
      <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, VK_SHIFT | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::END</autogen>
    </item>
    <item>
      <name>Shift + Delete = Forward Delete</name>
      <identifier>custom.delete</identifier>
      <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::DELETE, VK_SHIFT | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::FORWARD_DELETE</autogen>
    </item>
  </item>
</root>
```

I then clicked "Reload XML" in Karabiner and selected the new options, which took effect immediately! It seems to simulate the desired keypresses in every app.

Comment: I switched https://www.boastr.net/ since Karabiner doesn't work with MacOS 10.12 Sierra.

Answer (score 1):

You can set system-wide keybindings via the `~/Library/Keybindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` file ([more info](http://osxnotes.net/keybindings.html)) however it doesn't appear to be possible to distinguish between the left and right shift keys, so I think what you want to achieve is not possible.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! For my needs it's OK if left shift gets bound too.

Comment: Actually, I found this doesn't always work, it only works if the app implements a specific Cocoa protocol.